# Passing rvalue argument to parameter of non-const lvalue reference

Tags: c++, move-semantics

I'm unsure why the following code works (VC++ 2013):

```
void Foo(std::vector<int> &v) { }
```

In main:

```
std::vector<int> v;
Foo(std::move(v));
```

Because there is no Foo defined which takes an rvalue parameter or a const lvalue reference I was under the impression the above code would fail to compile. What is going on?

Thank you

Comment: Compile error for me on gcc 4.7, what compiler are you using?

Comment: Visual Studio's standard non-compliance strikes again! :-D (Seriously, that is the answer)

Comment: Set your warning level to `/W4` and Visual Studio will warn about a non-standard extension being used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**That code cannot work**. It must horribly break under any standard-conforming compiler. You're trying to initialize a non-const reference to an lvalue from an rvalue. Nope, won't work.

It is to be noted that both GCC and Clang reject it.

Comment: MSVC++ has historically always allowed non-const references to be initialized with temporary objects. I don't know what semantics it uses, although I'd hope it does a lifetime extension the same as const references to.

Comment: @MattMcNabb The last thing you said makes sense, otherwise they're doing something fundamentally wrong.